# data binding to html tag in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I was just wondering if it is possible to bind data using `DataBinder.Eval` on a html tag with `runat=server` attribute. For example i want to do something like:

```
<a href=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "file_name") %> runat="server" />
```

but it doesn't work. does this mean i have to use the **asp.net** hyperlink control?

Cheers,

Stephen

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

```
<a href='<%#Eval("file_name") %>' >Link text goes here...</a>
```

Comment: You need to change that last double quote to a single quote.

Comment: Oops! sorry, typo mistake :)

fixed.

Comment: thanks so much guys, worked perfectly :) hmm well just wondering is there any disadvantage to using <a> than <asp:hyperlink> ? thanks agian

Comment: With HyperLink you have a real server control having all server controls features like: enabled/disabled state, theme support, focus, possibility to be found via FindControl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It works if the element is inside a bindable control, like a DataList or a GridView, and you don't need server control:

```
<a href='<%# Eval("file_name") %>' />
```

Comment: thank you it work very good, can i ask why i have to use single quotes and double quotes wont work?